# Browsing Azure wiki from desktop application

Tags: azure, ado, wiki

I have a clone of `Azure` Wiki. Is there a way to view it on local machine. I can open in notepad with extension and so on. But is there a better viewer that will give the same experience as in the Web? Like you see all the pages with hierarchy and clicking will show it in the pan on right hand side?

I try to to download `Notepad++` and install md extensions and it helps to view the individual files but doesn't create a tree like structure of all pages.